# FPGA Applications

Tags: fpga, embedded

I am keen on learning about FPGA's. I am looking for some recommendations on cheap(reasonably) dev boards and suitable software suite.

I am also looking for some real work applications that I can build towards. A suitable project that I can develop that will show the insights into the benefits of using them. Blinking an LED is not much use as I can do that with an MCU in 5 seconds. Basically something that an MCU cannot do and therefore would need an FPGA.

Thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Let's discuss the difference between an FPGA and an MCU. Under what circumstances would you need to use an FPGA? an MCU? They serve for completely different purposes. It's not even fair to compare them.

Comment: From what I'v seen they are used a lot in DSP as they can handle a lot of sampling and data due to their ability work different signals in parallel. They are also used to implement MCU like architectures. So in that aspect why would one design an MCU on one when there are trusted MCU's available?

Comment: 1) for fun 2) to add some special high-speed function to the CPU, like ethernet routing, encryption, signal processiing.

Comment: Right so an MCU is used for instrumentations, sensors, and execution for tangible items. FPGAs are very flexible for sort of creating your own logic system. Like Wouter said, one is for accomplishing real physical tasks, one is used for basically creating your own computing system.

Comment: @KingDuken, I'm surprised you find FPGAs and MCU applications quite so distinct and incomparable. They clearly have specific areas where one has a big advantage over the other but they overlap considerably in the range of applications out there.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of stuff out there. Digilent have some nice little boards at less than $100 with an Artix FPGA on, and you can use the software from Xilinx. There are others too, such as Terrasic who have some good Altera stuff. Also there is quite a course on Coursera which is a good introduction (more an overview of the design process and also what is available from various vendors).

The LED flashing stuff is good to get up and running. Once you have that, it's fun to start putting small micro's on there and so on. PicoBlaze is excellently documented by xilinx, and you can get this running in a few hours. Also at OpenCores is stuff like openrisc, a more powerful uP. There are also plenty of very good tutorial sites out there (I like nandland).

Have fun!